# Keep the subprocess run

Tags: python, cursor

I have an exe file build from C++ to get the mouse shape in two states: hand or arrow. But in code it only detects one current time (run in only time and close), the output is state.
I call it in python to get the output in the Windows shell:

```
output = subprocess.check_output([r'C:\Users\TomCang\Desktop\tim voi tu khoa\mouse_detect.exe'])
```

It runs 1 time, gives me the state and stops.
I tried to make it run forever with:

```
while(True):
    output = subprocess.check_output([r'C:\Users\TomCang\Desktop\tim voi tu khoa\mouse_detect.exe'])
    sleep(1)
    print(output)
```

Every second it checks once, but when called once is the one time the Windows shell appears. How can I call it only once and run as long as I want with only one Windows shell appearing?

P.S.: I can't edit my C++ function because I lost the source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Instead of using the convenient function `check_output`, you would construct a [`Popen` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). This will start the process and let you control it while running. One possibility is to capture the output into a file object (usually known as "pipe" the output):

```
program = r'C:\Users\TomCang\Desktop\tim voi tu khoa\mouse_detect.exe'
with subprocess.Popen([program], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line)
```

- `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` ⇒ Pipe the stdout into the file object `p.stdout`
- `universal_newlines=True` ⇒ Make the file be read as a text instead of binary

The inner `for` loop will wait until there is output available from the program. So you don't need that `time.sleep(1)`.

Comment: I tried that solution, but it not work :(, it run only time like before.

Comment: @AlphaWolf If the program exited by itself then nothing will work.